# AFNetworking 500 response body

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking-2

I've been using AFNetworking 2.0 in my app.
I've noticed that if my web-service returns a 500 status code I do not get the body of the response.

Here is an example of my php code

```
try
{
    $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;Database = $database", $uid, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    return $conn;
}

catch( PDOException $e )
{
    $response->status(500);
    echo( "Connection Error: " . $e->getMessage() );
}
```

If I use a simple rest client this is an example of a response body.

```
Connection Error: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
```

However this seems to be the only response I can get from AFNetworking

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x15e58fa0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

This is the part of my objective-c code that does this.

```
...} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"%@",error.description);

    }];
```

Is there a way I can get the response body?

Edit: More code for clarification

Below is part of my subclass of AFHTTPSessionManager

```
@implementation MSMAMobileAPIClient

    + (MSMAMobileAPIClient *)sharedClient {
        static MSMAMobileAPIClient *_sharedClient = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _sharedClient = [[MSMAMobileAPIClient alloc] initWithDefaultURL];
        });

        return _sharedClient;
    }

    - (id)initWithDefaultURL {
        return [self initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@/mamobile/index.php/" ,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"serviceIPAddress"]]]];
    }

    - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {

        self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
        if (!self) {
            return nil;
        }
        self.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:@[[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer], [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]]];

        return self;
    }
```

I tried setting the response serializer to a AFCompoundResponseSerializer but it didn't seem to make a difference

Below is an example of a subclass that I call the Librarian.

```
-(void)searchForItemWithString:(NSString *)searchString withCompletionBlock:(arrayBlock)block {

    self.inventorySearchBlock = block;

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"query": searchString};

    [[MSMAMobileAPIClient sharedClient] GET:@"inventory/search" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        if (!responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON");
        } else {
            //do stuff with the json dictionary that's returned..
        }

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error.description);

    }];

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPDATE: I have created a github repository to contain the latest code I am using. All changes will be posted there. https://github.com/Hackmodford/HMFJSONResponseSerializerWithData

The answer comes from this issue on github.
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1397

gfiumara is the dev who came up with this. I have only slightly modified his subclass of AFJSONResponseSerializer to include an actual string instead of the NSData

```
//MSJSONResponseSerializerWithData.h

#import "AFURLResponseSerialization.h"

/// NSError userInfo key that will contain response data
static NSString * const JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey = @"JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey";

@interface MSJSONResponseSerializerWithData : AFJSONResponseSerializer

@end
```

---

```
//  MSJSONResponseSerializerWithData.m

#import "MSJSONResponseSerializerWithData.h"

@implementation MSJSONResponseSerializerWithData

- (id)responseObjectForResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
                           data:(NSData *)data
                          error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    if (![self validateResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response data:data error:error]) {
        if (*error != nil) {
            NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [(*error).userInfo mutableCopy];
            userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey] = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSError *newError = [NSError errorWithDomain:(*error).domain code:(*error).code userInfo:userInfo];
            (*error) = newError;
        }

        return (nil);
    }

    return ([super responseObjectForResponse:response data:data error:error]);
}

@end
```

Here is an example of how I use it in the failure block.

```
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey"]); 
    }];
```

Comment: Keep in mind that setting a value of `nil` to `userInfo[JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey]` will throw an exception. To circumvent this, use KVC. `setValue:forKey:` tests the value first to see if it's `nil`. If it is, it treats the instruction as though you had called `removeObjectForKey:` instead — which will gracefully do nothing if the object isn't there.

Comment: @James are you suggesting this instead? [userInfo setValue:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:JSONResponseSerializerWithDataKey];

Comment: For those who need it to be on a NSDictionary and not just on a simple string. Just deserialize the data like the one below.
            NSDictionary * d = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:error];

Comment: @Hackmodford have you check that your method gets called? The ``!self.error`` check in ``responseObject`` prevents this method from being called !!! (AFHTTPRequestOperation.m)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AFCompoundSerializer` to tell the AFNetworking framework how to process all of the possible responses it could receive. By default it will only try to map JSON. A compound serializer will work through the serializers until it finds one that doesn't raise an error.

---

You want to use:

```
+ (instancetype)compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:(NSArray *)responseSerializers
```

on `AFCompoundResponseSerializer` (in `AFURLResponseSerialization.h`).

You need to pass an array of serializers that can handle the response. One of the serializers in the array should be an instance of `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` to handle your error responses.

Comment: Is there a tutorial of this somewhere?

Comment: AFNetworking github page (in particular, the migration guide) is the place to go.

Comment: I've added an example of my AFHTTPSessionManager subclass. Did I setup the AFCompoundSerializer incorrectly?

Comment: K I changed it to this self.responseSerializer = [AFCompoundResponseSerializer compoundSerializerWithResponseSerializers:@[[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer], [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]]];
 and updated my question to reflect this, but the fail block is still called with the same result :(

Comment: How are you setting up the client and starting the request to the server? Is it actually using your subclass? Why do you need the subclass?

Comment: I basically use it so that I don't have to set the security settings and base url each time. It makes my librarian classes simpler to read. I have posted an example of a method from one of my "librarian" classes.

Comment: Looks like you'll need to do a little debugging to find out if / how your compound serialiser is being used

Answer (score 0):

If you include my category in your project, it's as simple as the following:

```
[mySessionManager POST:@"some-api" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary *responseObject) {
    ...
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    id responseObject = error.userInfo[kErrorResponseObjectKey];
    ... do something with the response ...
}];
```

Here's the code for my category. It swizzles AFURLSessionManager to inject a shim into the completion handler. The shim puts the response into the NSError's userInfo.

https://gist.github.com/chrishulbert/35ecbec4b37d36b0d608